# Как сделать чтобы команда работа только днем python

Tags: python

Есть команда:

```
@bot.command()
async def xp(ctx, amount=10):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        now = datetime.now()
        now_time = now.time()
        print(now_time)
        for ft in range(amount):
            if now_time > time(1,30) or now_time < time(8,00):
                print("nith")
            else:
                channel = bot.get_channel(id)
                message = await channel.send(random.choice(words))
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0,3))
                await message.delete()
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(5,10))
```

Но проблема в том, что если цикл ft начался до 01:30 он продолжить работать и после, как это можно исправить
Хочу чтобы ночью команда продолжала работу, если больше 01:30 и до 08, а дальше продолжала работать если цикл еще не закончился

Comment: что такое time(1,30)?

Comment: ну с 1:30 ночи, до 8 утра по сути должно быть

Comment: А вы посмотрите, что у вас в `now`. Там время `UTC` без учёта таймзоны. Его нужно в ваше локальное время перевести.

Comment: так а какая разница, мне пофиг локальное или нет, просто нужно чтобы цикл ночью останавливался

Comment: это понятно, что с 1.30 до 8. Конструкция time(1,30) в коде - это что? Функция?

Comment: @Эникейщик Это видимо `datetime.time`

Comment: @Эникейщик ну а как верно исправить

Comment: что исправить? вот вы написали time(1, 30). Откуда вы взяли это? Почему вы думаете, что это означает 1:30?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно обновлять текущее время в цикле, а иначе вы всегда сравниваете ваш промежуток с тем временем, в которое цикл запустился.

```
@bot.command()
async def xp(ctx, amount=10):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        for ft in range(amount):
            now_time = datetime.now().time()
            if now_time > time(1,30) or now_time < time(8,00):
                print("nith")
            else:
                channel = bot.get_channel(id)
                message = await channel.send(random.choice(words))
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0,3))
                await message.delete()
                await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(5,10))
```

Comment: а как мне сделать чтобы функция остановилась или ушла до утра в сон, а не просто все зафлудило "nith" @n1tr0xs

Comment: и насколько правильно я указал время

Comment: @sdhea я не очень понял что вы в итоге хотите, чтобы происходило, т.к. формулировка для меня туманная: *Хочу чтобы ночью команда продолжала работу, если больше 01:30 и до 08, а дальше продолжала работать если цикл еще не закончился*. Да и в асинхронном я не разбираюсь. Но предположу, что вам нужно вычесть из 8:00 текущее время и вызвать `await asyncio.sleep` с результатом вычитания, переведенным в секунды

Comment: разобрался уже сам